# Differential equation two solutions, how so?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve $7x^3y'=4*\sqrt{y}$ with $y(1)=1$ now I thought that Picard Lindelöf would tell me that there is a (at least in a local area for x=1) unique solution unfortunately I found two: 
$y(x)=(-\frac{1}{7x^2}+\frac{8}{7})^2, y(x)=(-\frac{1}{7x^2}-\frac{6}{7})^2$. Can somebody explain to me why this is the case here?

Comment: do you mean $7x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=4 \sqrt{y}$?

Comment: The second $y(x)$ does not satisfy the ODE (using the positive branch of the square root). If you pick the negative branch you are dealing with a different ODE, which explains the two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one isn't a solution to the differential equation. Clearly the RHS is non-negative.

However $\displaystyle y_2'(x)=-\frac{4(6x^2+1)}{49x^5}$ (courtesy of [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff+%28-1%2F%287x%5E2%29-%286%2F7%29%29%5E2)), therefore the LHS is $\displaystyle -\frac{4(6x^2+1)}{7x^2}\color{grey}{\leq 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\sqrt y$ means, as usual, the *non-negative* square root of $y$, your second solution isn't really a solution.  For that $y$, you have $7x^3y'=4\left(-\frac1{7x^2}-\frac67\right)=-4\sqrt y$.